# How to find nested classes using LESS

Tags: html, css, angular, less

I need to write specific CSS to be applied for individual html file

Currently using : Angular 1.5 with LESS

Currently I am using angular application, where header and footer are common but middle content will vary as below...

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="container">
     <div class="home-page">Home</div>
</div>    
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Here is the second page code

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="container">
     <div class="contact-us">Contact</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Now, I need footer to be fixed in second page and relative in the first page.
Here, each page has specific less file.

My problem is if I write `.footer{position:fixed}` in less file all the pages are effected.

I found solution like `Internal css is working in ContactUs.html` (or) `Adding new CSS in JS file using element`, but I wanted to know is there any way to resolve the issue using less or css file?

Please find [image: the image here] for reference. CSS needs to be applied whenever we see `roadmap-page` is loaded.

Comment: Is this snippet from your app component and are header and footer components themselves?

Comment: Your edit invalidates the answer. Why didn't you write this in the first place? Anyway, just add a distinguishing class to the footer in one page.

Comment: @MrLister We have many HTML files so it is difficult to distinguish footer. I mean we need to change code in 10 js files. So, is there any easy solution using LESS file

Comment: can you share us your real component.html and less file?

Comment: updated my Question with image

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS sibling selector **+** to achieve this. If the `.footer` is sibling to `.contact-us` then the position will be fixed. You can write the below CSS code in your common styles.css or styles.less file

```
.contact-us + .footer {
  position: fixed;

}

.home-page + .footer {
  position: relative;

}
```

If you dynamically want to set class to your footer component, It's better to use `@Input()` decorator. What I would do is

**footer.component.ts**

`@Input() styleClass = 'footer';`

**footer.component.html**

`<div [class]="styleClass">Footer text</div>`

**contacts.component.html**

`<app-footer [styleClass]="'footer-fixed'">Footer text</div>`

**home.component.html**

`<app-footer>Footer text</div>`

CSS

`.footer-fixed { position: fixed }
.footer { position: relative }`

Comment: `<div class="footer">Footer</div>` is it something like `app-footer`. right?

Comment: Yes it is application footer and common for all the pages

Comment: We have 10+ JS files. So, it will be difficult to add condition in all those files and now we need black background if it is a different theme. Cant we manage this in Less file

Comment: You said, you have only one common footer component for all the pages?

Comment: If every page in your app has a unique id or class name at the root, then it's possible using less / css

Comment: styleClass varaible should be initialized in all the controllers so, I need to change 10 js files and one html i.e. footer. So, instead of these many changes. I am asking is there anyway to implement in LESS file. Application is in production so, need to minimize the changes

Comment: You need not to initialize it in all the controllers. when you want a different style, then only you need to initialize it. what you mean by 10 js files, is it 10 footer files or 10 different components?

Comment: I mean 10 different controllers where styleClass needs to initialize and I am using Angular 1.5 not 2+